# Solve system of equation

Tags: systems-of-equations

I have an equation which looks like this:

$$\begin{align}3x^2+4x+y^2&=0 \\2xy+2y&=0 \end{align}$$

and I am not able to get all four possible solutions by hand. Maybe someone can help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE :) What have you tried out so far?

Comment: Transform the first equation to y=... and then insert it into the second one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**;
Factor the second equation first:
$$2xy+2y=2y(x+1)=0.$$

Comment: Thank you, got it

Answer (score 0):

$2xy+2y=0\Rightarrow 2y(x+1)=0$, if $y=0$, then let's try to find a solution from the first equation, $3x^2+4x=0\Rightarrow x(3x+4)=0 \Rightarrow x=0$ or $x = -\frac{4}{3}$.

Now if $x=-1$, we have $3(-1)^2+4(-1)+y^2 = 3-4+y^2=0\Rightarrow y=\pm1$

Comment: Thank you, got it